# Get array of selected items by indexes in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, 1 holds the data and 1 holds the indexes that I need to use to reference the items I need to return. I want to loop through `myData` and return every item whose index matches in `myIndexes`.

**Data**

```
myData = [
   { "name": "Do This",
     "isEditable": true
   },
   { "name": "Do That",
     "isEditable": false
   },
   { "name": "Do It Again",
     "isEditable": false
   },
   { "name": "Do It One More Time",
     "isEditable": false
   }
];
```

**Indexes**

```
myIndexes = [0, 2, 3];
```

**Failed Attempts**

```
myData[index[myIndexes]]; // this works for 1 index, not multiple
```

Comment: First of all, the syntax of `myIndexes` is not correct.  Do you mean simply `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Can't you loop through `indexes` and pull out the matching members of `myData`?

Comment: Yeah, just copied straight from dev tools. That's how it showed there.

Comment: I've been trying to loop but I can't find an example that works for this instance so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by taking a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the index array. This will loop over `myIndexes` and make a new array by looking up the corresponding element in `myData` for each index:

```js
var myData = [
    { "name": "Do This",
      "isEditable": true
    },
    { "name": "Do That",
      "isEditable": false
    },
    { "name": "Do It Again",
      "isEditable": false
    },
    { "name": "Do It One More Time",
      "isEditable": false
    }
 ];

var myIndexes = [0, 2, 3];
 
var selected = myIndexes.map(index => myData[index])
console.log(selected)
```

EDIT based on comment:

If your environment can't support `map` you could always opt for the old-school `for` loop:

```js
var myData = [
    { "name": "Do This",
      "isEditable": true
    },
    { "name": "Do That",
      "isEditable": false
    },
    { "name": "Do It Again",
      "isEditable": false
    },
    { "name": "Do It One More Time",
      "isEditable": false
    }
 ];

var myIndexes = [0, 2, 3];

var selected = []
for (var i = 0; i < myIndexes.length; i++){
  selected.push(myData[myIndexes[i]])
}
console.log(selected)
```

Comment: Thanks that looks great but when I try it I am getting `ReferenceError: index is not defined`

Comment: @UXCODA are you getting that when you run the above snippet?

Comment: Yes if I follow it down with breakpoints it fails on `index` and shows that message

Comment: @UXCODA - Hmm, that's strange that the snippet is throwing an error when you click `Run code snippet`. What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, its not throwing an error on running the snippet. It's showing that error when I try to implement into my code.

Comment: Oh, `index` is defined as an the argument to the map callback — maybe there's a typo? `myIndexes.map(index => myData[index])` <-- it need to have index in both places.

Comment: Hi actually I'm not sure if `map` is supported in the environment I'm working in :( I'm still getting used to SAP

Comment: @UXCODA see the edit, you should be able to use a for loop almost anywhere javascript is served.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I actually got both methods working now.